# Estimated simple linear regression model

Tags: statistics, regression, regression-analysis, linear-regression

Consider the simple linear regression model $y=50 + 10x + \varepsilon$ where $\varepsilon$ is $NID (0,16)$. Suppose that $n=20$ pairs of observations are used to fit this model. Generate $500$ samples of $20$ observations, drawing one observation for each level of $x=1,1.5,2,...,10$ for each sample.

a. For each sample compute the least-squares estimates of the slope and intercept. Construct histograms of the sample values of $\widehat{\beta _{0}}$ and $\widehat{\beta _{1}}$ . Discuss the shapes of these histograms.

b. For each sample, compute an estimate of $E(y|x=5)$. Construct a histogram of the estimates you obtained and discuss the shape of the histograms.

c. For each sample, compute a $95\%$ CI on the slope. How many of these intervals contain the true value $\beta _{1}=10$? Is this what we would expect?

d. For each estimate of $E(y|x=5)$ in part b, compute the $95\%$ CI. How many of these intervals contain the true value of $E(y|x=5)=100$? Is this what we would expect?

Please help me how can I do? I'm stuck in first question.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: Actually I know how to solve it by using R programme of statistic but it's not allowed to use that programme. All is this question and I don't how can  I find estimated slope and intercept :(

Comment: Minitab might be used. How I can get 500 samples?

Comment: http://www.quantdec.com/misc/MAT8406/Homework/Exercise_2_23.pdf     Check this page. But when I try in R programme, I get different solutions.